# Subsetting blank rows from data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

How can I subset rows from a data frame if rows in a given column are blank or NA. For example:

```
    x <- c(1,2,3,4,"","","")
    y <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
    z <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700)
    xyz <- data.frame(x,y,z)
    View(xyz)
```

[image]

```
g1 <- subset(xyz, subset=(x > 0))
```

Returns:

> Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(x, 0) : > not meaningful for factors

How can I get it to return a new data frame that's a subset of the original but only containing rows where X column is greater than zero?

Comment: `subset(xyz,x!="")
  x y   z
1 1 A 100
2 2 B 200
3 3 C 300
4 4 D 400`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you created your data frame, you specified that `x` should be a factor variable.

(Technically you specified that it should be character, but `data.frame` has read your mind and converted it to factor for you. Again, technically you didn't specify that it should be character, but R has read your mind and, because you tried to combine numbers and characters in the one vector, it's coerced them all into a vector of character mode.)

Because of this, "greater than zero" doesn't make sense as a comparison operator in this context. I'm going to read your mind and conclude that you actually want `x` to be numeric, but with an allowance for situations where the value is not available. In that case, you should do

```
xyz$x <- as.numeric(as.character(xyz$x))
subset(xyz, !is.na(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `x` is stored as a factor, being greater than a value doesn't make any sense here. You can use indexing:

```
xyz[xyz$x != "",]
#   x y   z
# 1 1 A 100
# 2 2 B 200
# 3 3 C 300
# 4 4 D 400
```

`NA` is different to `""`, and you can do a logical test for that using `is.na()`. So if the values in this case were `NA` rather than `""`, `xyz[!is.na(xyz$x),]` would do the trick